# Getting the iPhone X safe area using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone, viewport, iphone-x

We have `safe-area-inset-left`, `safe-area-inset-right`, `safe-area-inset-top`, and `safe-area-inset-bottom` in CSS, but how can we get those values using JavaScript?

Comment: @Scott How is this a duplicated? I have same question and the duplicated link gives no solution to this question.

Answer (score 14):

From https://benfrain.com/how-to-get-the-value-of-phone-notches-environment-variables-env-in-javascript-from-css/. You can find more context in the link.

Within CSS

```
:root {
    --sat: env(safe-area-inset-top);
    --sar: env(safe-area-inset-right);
    --sab: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
    --sal: env(safe-area-inset-left);
}
```

Within JS

```
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue("--sat")
```